# How to alias C library functions?

Tags: c

I have a static C library that I can build with different compile time options (e.g. _BUILD_SMALL, _BUILD_FAST).  It has a function

```
void Foo(void);
```

I would like to use a single instance of a benchmarking tool to benchmark the "small" and the "fast" versions of the library.  I don't want to use .dlls.

How can I link to the "small" and the "fast" libraries and alias the function names so I can call the small version and the fast version.  Ideally it would look something like:

```
void benchmark(void)
{
  FAST_Foo();

  SMALL_Foo();
}
```

More information:

The library can be built with different optimizations options -Os versus -O3.  Also, the algorithms vary slightly (i.e. cached values vs looking up values always).  I want to compare the size vs speed tradeoffs of the different versions.  I'd like the unit tests and benchmarking to be ran on both versions of the library the easiest way possible.

Comment: This question is very very unclear.

Comment: Why not simply build multiple versions with various options turned on/off and benchmark each one?

Comment: You cannot combine both functions in a single link if they are named the same (and are not static).

Comment: @EdS.  I can build the multiple libraries and produce foo_fast.a and foo_small.a.  I was hoping to wrap these and run the unit tests and benchmarking on both libraries in a single step instead of building two versions of the unit tests and benchmarking.

Comment: @Falmarri what would make this more clear for you?

Comment: Seems very clear to me, and for benchmarking purposes it makes a lot of sense to have both versions of the functions available at the same time. I think just the use of word _aliasing_ confuses people, because _renaming_ is actually the goal here for the purpose of being able to link multiple versions of the same functions (and variables).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a variation of the method as given by @Michał Górny (I run out of comment space there)...

You could create an include file of the following form:

```
/* Automatically created file - do not edit or ugly dinosaur will eat you */
#ifndef PREFIX
#  define RENAME(f)
#else
#  define RENAME(f) PREFIX ## f
#endif

/* list all the function and variables you want to rename here in one place */
#define func_foo RENAME(func_foo)
#define func_bar RENAME(func_bar)
/* ... many more ... */

#undef RENAME
```

At least `gcc` allows you to specify the inclusion of a header file from command line with option `-include rename.h` (assuming this file is called `rename.h`). Because you use `gcc` lookalike options (`-O3` and `Os`), I am assuming you use `gcc` in the rest of this answer. Otherwise, if your C compiler is reasonable, you should be able to do it in some similar way.

You can create easily two or even three versions of your library that can be linked in at the same time if you want, by providing different options for your C compiler (here through `CFLAGS` setting):

```
CFLAGS += -include rename.h -DPREFIX=fast_ -D_BUILD_FAST -O3 -DBENCHMARKING
CFLAGS += -include rename.h -DPREFIX=small_ -D_BUILD_SMALL -Os -DBENCHMARKING
CFLAGS += -D_BUILD_FAST -O2
```

If your library header files look very regular and if you declare the library private functions `static`, then it is easy to extract the functions from those header files by some dummy script using very simple regular expressions to automatically generate the `rename.h` file for you. This is a natural build target if you are using `make` or something similar. All the global variables also need to be renamed using the same method to allow simultaneous use.

There are three main points with this solution:

1. The ugly renaming business can be hidden in one file, *you do not need to edit the actual source files* - especially you do not need to clutter the source files but can keep them clean and easy to read.
2. The renaming can be easily *automated*, if you follow some simple principles (coding conventions followed for the header files and the header files will declare all the global variables and functions).
3. There is no reason to make benchmarking more cumbersome by needing to run your test program multiple times (this is relevant if you are as lazy as I am and dislike repetive tasks as violently as I do - I know many people do not care, it is somewhat a matter of preference).

Comment: I like your approach a lot! But I have one question, though: Is it allowed by the C standard to use a preprocessor macro for defining just an "alias" to the function name without writing the arguments as you would do in a function-like macro? I ask this because if you need to write each function arguments in the renaming file, then the approach would soon become unpractical.

Comment: The above macro trick is C/C++ standard compliant. For example, by having `#define PREFIX my_wrapper_` and then having `#define malloc RENAME(malloc)` is exactly like saying `#define malloc my_wrapper_malloc`. Whenever in the remaining compilation unit you would say `malloc`, it would be replaced by the preprocessor as `my_fancy_malloc`, whether it would be a function call or function pointer or whatever. This preprocessor conversion does not involve any interpretation of any meaning whatsoever. The operation is basically a string replacement. The C macros are really dumb.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @FooF  For a moment I was confused because everybody that makes an alias to a function with the preprocessor, always do it using the "function-like macros" paradigm (with arguments), and seeing it applied in a raw way with no arguments is not common. Thanks a lot for confirming that's compliant.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be: keep the same name for both and call appropriately depending on the compile time option set.

```
ifdef SMALL_FOO
void foo() {

/* Small foo code */
}
#endif

ifdef BIG_FOO
void foo() {

/* Big foo code */
}
#endif
```

Set the `SMALL_FOO/BIG_FOO` during compilation with `-d`.

Comment: I had considered this.  The current implementation would require some duplication to do this, but I think it could be done.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick solution, you can use macro to mangle the function name like:

```
#ifdef FAST
#   define FUNC(x) FAST_##x
#else
#   define FUNC(x) SLOW_##x
#endif

void FUNC(Foo)();
```

And now with `-DFAST` the library with `FAST_Foo` will be built; and without it, one with `SLOW_Foo`. Just note that you need to use the `FUNC()` macro in the implementation part as well (and whenever you are referring to that function from inside the library), and `#ifdef FAST` to switch between fast/slow code.

Just *please* don't use that in a production code.

Comment: I would also add a `#ifdef ALIAS` which when false would bypass the above and in the `#else` clause would have `#define FUNC(x) x`. Then you wouldn't need to use the macro in the implementation part.

Comment: I was thinking about this.  I was looking for an aliasing solution, but I had considered building specific "mangled" library functions, then doing a #ifdef FAST #define Foo FAST_Foo() #endif

Comment: I agree with the renaming but I personally do not like the way as suggested here. I dislike changing how the function prototypes appear. You cannot search for them using regular expressions any more, some tools to deal with C files will get confused, and it clutters the view. I would prefer doing prior to function definition/declaration. E.g in the above example, say `#define Foo FUNC(Foo)` (using your `FUNC()` macro and `Foo()` functions where `FUNC()` macro should be better named differently though if used this way). Then you can just have normal looking function prototype.

Comment: @FooF: hm, yes, and then also removing the ugliness would be easier since you'd just have to drop the macros.

Answer (score 2):

If you attempt to link in both static libraries to the same executable, the second library listed in your link line will not have any effect, because all the symbols it provided was satisfied already by the first library. If you provided simple unique wrapper functions to call `Foo`, it would still fail, now because of multiple definitions. Here is an example:

```
/* x.c */
extern void Y_Bar ();
extern void Z_Bar ();
int main ()
{
    Y_Bar();
    Z_Bar();
}
```

This main calls unique wrapper functions, which are provided in `liby.a` and `libz.a`.

```
/* y.c in liby.a */
#include <stdio.h>
void Y_Bar () {
    extern void Foo ();
    Foo();
}
void Foo () {
    printf("%s\n", "that Foo");
}

/* z.c in libz.a */
#include <stdio.h>
void Z_Bar () {
    extern void Foo ();
    Foo();
}
void Foo () {
    puts("this foo");
}
```

Attempting to link the executable with `-ly -lz` will fail.

The easiest work around for you is to build two separate executables. Your benchmark driver could then execute both executables to compare their relative performance.

Comment: I've selected this as the easiest solution for production code.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you can build the library, changing the compile time options, so why not edit the code to change the names of the functions in each.  (You'd be making two different versions of your library.)

Comment: the compile time options are passed to the preprocessor, the code doesn't change (that's the goal anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `-D option when call gcc, like -D_FAST_, -D_SMALL_,` or your can received a input parameter when using make, like use make `CFG=FAST, make CFG=SMALL,` in your `makefile`, you can define, when get parameter`FAST, link to FAST library`.